# Issue with displaying Results to Grid, despite selecting the option

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am a learner who needs the community assistance to better my understanding and proficiency. I appeal for your time and expertise.

I am using SQL Server Express 2022 and SSMS v19.0.2, despite having results to grid as the default, I still checked that from tools - options - SQL Query is set to 'Results to Grid'.

I have created a Database called HR, a table called Workers with three columns (the first being a pk with `IDENTITY`), set all the necessary permissions. When I ran a simple query '`INSERT INTO Workers VALUES ('Sam', 'Doe'`). My expectation is to see this data inserted into the columns and shows in the Result pane, what I see after several attempts, with uninstallations and reinstallations is to see only Editor and Message pane without Result Pane.
The Editor shows the query, while the Message shows, '

> (1 row affected), Completion time: 2023-04-08T10:55:43.7889431+01:00'.

At the bottom, it shows;

> Query executed successfully.

I have tried this in Windows 10 and 11, but I got the same results.

Please, help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no problem or bug, but it is a wrong expectation ;-)

When doing an `INSERT`, there is no (default) resultset. The option you have selected is being used for example when doing a `SELECT` statement, where you can see the results in grid format.
Other options are in text, which will show the resultset in text, or save to file, which will ask you to save the file.

Those 3 can also be changed in the SSMS toolbar:
[image]

Results to grid:

[image]

Results to text:

[image]

In your case, you might want to run

```
SELECT * FROM Workers
```

To see some results

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the data that was inserted, you may find the [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) clause useful.

```
INSERT
    dbo.your_table
(
    columns
)
OUTPUT 
    Inserted.* 
SELECT
    some_stuff;
```

SQL Server Management Studio only displays rows returned to the client. The `OUTPUT` clause ensures the inserted rows are returned.